# Call method in subclass

Tags: java

My code is as following

```
class Shape {
    void drawShape() {
        System.out.println("shape drawn of shape class");
    }

    void printStr() {
        System.out.println("checking");
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    void drawShape() {
        System.out.println("shape drawn of circle class");
    }

    public void printNumber() {
        System.out.println("1");

    }
}

     public class TestShape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape shape = new Circle();
        shape.drawShape();
        shape.printStr();
    }
}
```

here is the output

```
shape drawn of circle circle
checking
```

when i am calling shap.drawShape(), It is executing the method of my subclass, But when i am trying to call shape.printNumber() compiler is giving error , My question is with the same object if sub class method is executing, (i know it is overriding) then why can't i call the subclass method?

Answer (score 1):

Because Java is statically-typed and your declaration is of the subclass. To be able to call `printNumber,` you *must* use:

```
    Circle shape = new Circle();
    shape.drawShape();
    shape.printStr();
```

`drawShape()` works fine due to polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The `printNumber` method is defined in class `Circle` but not in class `Shape`.

Your variable `shape` has the type `Shape`. You cannot call `printNumber` on it, because that method does not exist in class `Shape`.

Comment: yeah i am agree but if you see the result, output of shape.drawShape() is executing the subclass method, if this can execute subclass method then why can't i access shape.printNumber()

Comment: As others have said because it is not declared in Shape. drawShape is declared in Shape so a reference of shape knows about it. At runtime the correct method is called as the true type is checked (runtime type information). If you declared a printNumber in Shape it would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

when you call

```
Shape shape = new Circle();
shape.printStr();
```

you're trying to call a method that does not exist for a Shape

If you do

```
Circle shape = new Circle();
shape.printStr();
```

then the compiler will know where to search

Comment: it will print it...try it

Answer (score 0):

Type of your object is Shape and that is super class which does not have printNumber method. when you call the drawShape it calls the subclass method because of override. Hope it makes clear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not understanding the idea of inheritance. Here's an analogy: A circle is a shape, but a shape isn't always going to be a circle now, is it?